# Multiple ADC's interfacing to FPGA

Tags: fpga, adc

I am looking for a 32-channel ADC (24-bit resolution) which can simultaneously sample all the signals. But I could find only 8-channel ADC with the above requirements.

So, is it possible that I can use multiple 8-channel ADC's to interface with FPGA at the same time?

Comment: There are several problems with this question. **A**) This question is off-topic because you are asking for a product recommendation. **B**) you are not mentioning the frequency you want to sample at. **C**) you are not mentioning if you're going for a SMD solution or DIP. I could go on... but because of **A**), everything else just... falls apart.

Comment: This is not a product recommendation. I am asking if it is logically possible to interface two or more external ADC's to a FPGA at the same time?

Comment: Hmm, looks like I misinterpreted your first sentence.

Comment: the first two sentences are actually useless

Comment: @jsotola If I did not write the first two sentences, people could have asked me why would I want to connect two external ADC's at the same time. I just gave the reason behind it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, completely possible. Pick an ADC that allows synchronization of conversions, ADS1278 for example.

You can read the conversions out from the ADCs with a single interface (bandwidth permitting) or multiple- the key thing is to synchronize the conversions themselves, and you can read out the data at your leisure (at least until the next set of conversions arrives).

With an FPGA you will have no problem generating the proper SYNC signal (or whatever your ADC of choice requires).

Comment: Not all ADCs have a SYNC signal/command. Of course, that's a constraint on selecting an ADC itself.